# Angular function calling inside table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-5

I want to use ajax delete function:

```
angular_app.controller('contacts_controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache',
    function ($scope, $http, $templateCache) {
        $scope.delete(id) {
            alert('del: '+id);
        };
    //....
        }
    ]);
```

..and an assist function

```
function deleteContact(id) {
    angular.element(document.getElementById("contacts_controller")).scope().delete(id);
}
```

And angular table to calling delete (I use laravel, so `{[{` and `}]}` instead of `{{` and `}}`).

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in data">
    <td>{[{ x.id }]}</td>
    <td>{[{ x.name }]}</td>
    <td>
        <button onClick="deleteContact({[{ x.id }]})">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How to  put to work the delete contact. `onClick="deleteContact(3)"` works well.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-click instead of onclick.

```
 <button ng-click="delete(x.id)">Delete</a>
```